# Is it possible to access battery usage/time on screen information of all applications in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Sorry if the question is worded poorly. Basically I'm trying to programmatically access the time on screen data that you see in the picture (for example 7.5 hrs on screen for Reddit). Is this something that is possible to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No it's impossible.

iOS since first versions is a sandbox OS. It means that each app can only access to their documents and root folder but doesn't have access to other app. But Apple, add some mechanisms to share datas between apps (like app groups). But these mechanisms doesn't work for system app. React Native is based on iOS native implementation.

You can only got the total amount of battery using libraries : [(react-native) How to detect the battery level in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129934/react-native-how-to-detect-the-battery-level-in-react-native)

More about sandbox : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)